# WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending the following invalid capabilities: [applicationName, firefox_profile];

Tags: selenium, firefox

Please I have upgraded to Selenium 4.3.0, and i run my test plan on Jenkins, I use Firefox, and I am getting this error :
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending the following invalid capabilities: [applicationName, firefox_profile]; Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/ :
I have checked a lot of fixes, but i can use them because i have in my project custom browse factory page, can you please help me how to fix this :
This is my browse factory page  :

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BrowserFactory.class.getName());

private static final String DRIVERS_PATH = "src//test//resources//com//stacks//bdd//selenium//driver//";
private static final String DEBUG = "debug_OMI360";
private static final String DEBUG_FIREFOX = "debug";
private static final String NO_DEBUG = "no_debug";
private static final Browser BROWSER = SystemProperties.getSeleniumBrowser();
private static final Boolean SELENIUM_GRID = SystemProperties.getSeleniumGrid();
private static final URL SELENIUM_GRID_URL = SystemProperties.getSeleniumGridUrl();
private static final Boolean SELENIUM_GRID_DEBUG = SystemProperties.getSeleniumGridDebug();
private static final String LOCALE = SystemProperties.getLocale();
private static final Boolean IS_WINDOWS = System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows");

private static Map<String, WebDriver> drivers = new HashMap<>();

private BrowserFactory() {
}

public static CustomWebDriver getBrowser() {
    WebDriver driver;
        logger.info("Creating driver.");
        switch (BROWSER) {
        case CHROME:
            driver = getChromeDriver();
            break;
        case FIREFOX:
            driver = getFirefoxDriver();
            break;
        case IE:
            driver = getInternetExplorerDriver();
            break;
        case EDGE:
            driver = getEdgeDriver();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Supported browsers are " + EnumSet.allOf(Browser.class));
        }
        drivers.put(BROWSER.toString(), driver);
    return new CustomWebDriver(driver);
}

private static WebDriver getEdgeDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", DRIVERS_PATH + "MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
    return new EdgeDriver();
}

private static WebDriver getInternetExplorerDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", DRIVERS_PATH + "IEDriverServer.exe");
    return new InternetExplorerDriver();
}

private static WebDriver getFirefoxDriver() {
    if (SELENIUM_GRID) {
        FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
        fp.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", LOCALE);
        fp.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/msword");
        fp.setPreference("network.proxy.type",1);
        fp.setPreference("network.proxy.http","isp-ceg.emea.cegedim.grp");
        fp.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl","isp-ceg.emea.cegedim.grp");
        fp.setPreference("network.proxy.ftp","isp-ceg.emea.cegedim.grp");
        fp.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port",3128);
        fp.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port",3128);
        fp.setPreference("network.proxy.ftp_port",3128);
        fp.setPreference("print.always_print_silent", true);
        fp.setPreference("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings",true);
        fp.setPreference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on","localhost,127.0.0.1,*.cegedim.com,*.cegedim.cloud,*.cegedim.grp,*.cegedim.hds,*.cegedim.clt,*.monlogicielmedical.com");
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.Capability.PROFILE, fp);
        // https://confluencechs.cegedim.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=44045964#SWFDO-PortainerforBDD(pswfbdd01.emea.cegedim.grp)-ConnecttoSelenium'snodedesktopbyVNC:
        if(SELENIUM_GRID_DEBUG) {
            options.setCapability("applicationName", DEBUG_FIREFOX);
        } else {
            options.setCapability("applicationName", NO_DEBUG);
        }
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(SELENIUM_GRID_URL, options);
        driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
        if(SELENIUM_GRID_DEBUG) {
            // Bear in mind that in non-debug images, the maximize window command won't
            // work. You can use the resize window command instead. Also, some browser
            // drivers allow specifying window size in capabilities.
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            logger.info("driver maximized");
        }
        return driver;
    } else { WebDriver webDriver ;
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            //  DRIVERS_PATH + (IS_WINDOWS ? "geckodriver.exe" : "geckodriver"));
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setProfile(new FirefoxProfile())
                .addPreference("intl.accept_languages", LOCALE);
        options.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/msword");
        options.addPreference("print.always_print_silent", true);
        options.addPreference("print.show_print_progress", false);
        webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        return webDriver;
    }
}

private static WebDriver getChromeDriver() {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--lang=" + LOCALE);
    options.addArguments("--lang=" + LOCALE);
    if (SELENIUM_GRID) {
        options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        // https://confluencechs.cegedim.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=44045964#SWFDO-PortainerforBDD(pswfbdd01.emea.cegedim.grp)-ConnecttoSelenium'snodedesktopbyVNC:
        if(SELENIUM_GRID_DEBUG) {
            options.setCapability("applicationName", DEBUG);
        } else {
            options.setCapability("applicationName", NO_DEBUG);
        }
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(SELENIUM_GRID_URL, options);
        driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
        if(SELENIUM_GRID_DEBUG) {
            // Bear in mind that in non-debug images, the maximize window command won't
            // work. You can use the resize window command instead. Also, some browser
            // drivers allow specifying window size in capabilities.
            Waiter.sleep(1500);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
        else {
            Waiter.sleep(1500);
            driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920,1080));

    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

@Ahmad Ghalwash can you try replacing the following line in your code

```
 options.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.Capability.PROFILE, fp);
```

with this one:

```
options.setProfile(fp);
```

Comment: first ketanvj Thanks for reply, i have done this bit still have same error :                                                                                                                                                      WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending the following invalid capabilities: [applicationName]; Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/                                               it is for "  options.setCapability("applicationName", DEBUG_FIREFOX);"

Comment: @AhmadGhalwash I tried to check the documentation but no luck so far.  Is your test running properly? As this is just a warning. I was able to execute it with this warning in my machine.

Comment: yes, it is running, but taking very long time, and sometimes fails also